# If function in "onsubmit" is undefined the POST request is executed anyway?

Tags: javascript, html, post, request, pug

I have got this form (written in JADE):

```
form(onsubmit="return validateForm();" action = '/do/something', method = 'post'
....
  div
    button(type='submit')= t('myButtons.submit')
```

When I press the submit button before the page fully loads, I got the error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: validateForm is not defined

That makes sense IMO. But how come the post request is executed anyway?

I tried this

```
form(onsubmit="return validateForm() || false;" action = '/do/something', method = 'post'
```

I also tried this:

```
form(onsubmit="return validateForm || false;" action = '/do/something', method = 'post'
```

I also tried to put validateForm inside `$(document).ready(function(){}` as well as putting it before `$(document).ready(function(){}`.

But the result is the same. The POST request is executed. Only when the page is fully loaded, the form would work correctly.

Comment: You can return false in validateForm to cancel submission if page is not loaded. Alternatively, you can hide the button until the page has loaded.

Comment: Nope. I tried this too. I also tried to put validateForm inside  $(document).ready(function(){} as well as before  $(document).ready(function(){}. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> But how come the post request is executed anyway?

When you submit a form, it will be submitted unless something prevents it.

If the JavaScript you run in response to the submit event throws an exception, then it isn't preventing the form from submitting.

Therefore, it submits.

> ```
> return validateForm() || false;
> ```

I think you are trying to test if `validateForm` is defined here, and to use `false` if it is not.

However, you are actually testing if the *return value of calling `validatorForm` is true*. If the function isn't defined, you get an exception and the script aborts.

To do that you would need something more like:

```
if (typeof validateForm !== "undefined") {
    return validateForm();
} else {
    return false;
}
```

… but I can't see what circumstance would cause you to have your `validateForm` function defined conditionally … and if it isn't defined then having your form simply (and silently) do nothing is a *terrible* fail state.

> I also tried to put validateForm inside $(document).ready(function(){}

The stops the function from being a global and ensures that it won't be defined in the scope of the `onsubmit=` intrinsic event attribute.

> as well as before $(document).ready(function(){}.

It shouldn't matter where you define the function; just so long as you do and that it is a global.

(Or, if you switch to the mordern practise of binding your event handlers with JavaScript, so long as it is in scope for your call to `addEventListener`).